# Finding items that corresponds to other items in the same collection using LINQ

Tags: linq

I'm trying to wrap my head around this in LINQPAD and keep failing. Basically I need the entries that have a corresponding entry ending with "_SCHEMA".

So from the list below, I need "Dumbo" entry only

```
void Main()
{
 var users = new List<User> {new User{Name="Dummy"}, new User{Name="Dumbo"}, 
new User{Name="Dunno"}, new User{Name="Dumbo_SCHEMA"}};

}

class User
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Do you mean you need entries which *do* have a corresponding entry ending with _SCHEMA? Otherwise surely you'd want "Dummy" and "Dunno" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
from user in users
    where users.Any(inner => inner.Name == user.Name + "_SCHEMA")
    select user
```

**Edit:** Beware of performance issues on too large sets.